# Get data attr in scss

Tags: sass

I want to get data attr which is a number from HTML in my scss file and do a for loop on elements.

so here's what i did :

**HTML :**

```
 <figure class="inner" data-attr="8"></figure>
```

**SCSS**

```
[data-attr] {
  $no: attr('data-attr') !global;
}
```

and

```
@for $i from 0 through $no {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        left: $no;
      }
    }
```

but I got an error :

> Error: attr("data-attr") is not an integer.$no: attr('data-attr') !global

Comment: That's not possible, scss is compiled to css and is never near the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take a different approach.

SASS is a pre-processor that compiles into a CSS file. You can't use a SASS loop to generate CSS output based on a value that you don't have at the time of compilation.

Without knowing what you're actually attempting to do, it's not possible to suggest an alternative solution either.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738487/scss-for-loop-get-the-length-from-data-attribute

This is not true then, right ?

Comment: I'm remarkably surprised the answer you linked to was accepted. It's plainly false. SASS has no knowledge whatsoever of your HTML elements when it compiles. I can't understand a scenario in which that works.